# How To Submit Values Of Multiple Variable Of One Database Table Into One Input Field?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hello Everyone,
                i have built one basic HTML form using PHP for submitting data in one database table, list of variable that i use in my database table are

id, a1, a2, a3, a, a4, a5, a6, date, color, today

and i am using below HTML form to submit data in my database table

```
<form method="post" action="" autocomplete="off">
  TODAY: <input type="text" name="today" size="5" value="<?php $theDate = date("d/m/y"); echo " $theDate"; ?>"><br>
DATE:<input type="text" name="date" size="5" align="absmiddle" value="<?php
$current_dayname = date("l");

echo $date = date("d/m/y",strtotime('monday next week')).' <br>to<br> '.date("d/m/y",strtotime("sunday next week"));  
?>">
<table><tr><td><input type="text" name="a1" size="1" value="<?php echo $query2['a1']; ?>">
<input type="text" name="a2" size="1" value="<?php echo $query2['a2']; ?>">
<input type="text" name="a3" size="1" value="<?php echo $query2['a3']; ?>"></td><td>
<input type="text" name="a" size="2" value="<?php echo $query2['a']; ?>"></td><td>
<input type="text" name="a4" size="1" value="<?php echo $query2['a4']; ?>">
<input type="text" name="a5" size="1" value="<?php echo $query2['a5']; ?>">
<input type="text" name="a6" size="1" value="<?php echo $query2['a6']; ?>"></td></tr></table>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
```

now the issue is that i have to use three input field for values a1,a2,a3 and also for a4,a5,a6 and i want to use only one input field for these variables, so that it is easy to enter values in it..

also check image of my HTML form code

[image]

And I Want HTML form looks like below after modification:

[image]

can anyone help me in order to combine these input fields

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

It works for me(array elements can have string datatype (`'words'`) and numeric (`3`, `3.4324`)):

```
<form method="post" action="" autocomplete="off">
  TODAY: <input type="text" name="today" size="5" value="<?php $theDate = date("d/m/y"); echo " $theDate"; ?>"><br>
DATE:<input type="text" name="date" size="5" align="absmiddle" value="<?php
$current_dayname = date("l");

echo $date = date("d/m/y",strtotime('monday next week')).' <br>to<br> '.date("d/m/y",strtotime("sunday next week"));  
?>">
<?php if(is_string($query2['a1']) || is_numeric($query2['a1']) 
        && is_string($query2['a2']) || is_numeric($query2['a2']) 
        && is_string($query2['a3']) || is_numeric($query2['a3']) 
        && is_string($query2['a4']) || is_numeric($query2['a4']) 
        && is_string($query2['a5']) || is_numeric($query2['a5']) 
        && is_string($query2['a6']) || is_numeric($query2['a6']) 
        && is_string($query2['a']) || is_numeric($query2['a'])): ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="a1a2a3" size="3" value="<?= $query2['a1'].$query2['a2'].$query2['a3']; ?>">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="a" size="2" value="<?= $query2['a']; ?>">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="a4a5a6" size="3" value="<?= $query2['a4'].$query2['a5'].$query2['a6']; ?>">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php endif; ?>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
```

[this code in php gen for getting HTML snippet below](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bfc3f863e8622708fcd2b973327349a8f8048903)

```html
<form method="post" action="" autocomplete="off">
  TODAY: <input type="text" name="today" size="5" value=" 11/10/19"><br>
DATE:<input type="text" name="date" size="5" align="absmiddle" value="14/10/19 <br>to<br> 20/10/19">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="a1a2a3" size="3" value="a1a2a3">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="a" size="2" value="ww">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="a4a5a6" size="3" value="a456">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
```

Comment: Show me errors please, cause it works fine for me. What is data type `$query` has? You've used it as an `array`.

Comment: I've updated my answer and you can see it works fine.